# Test phonegap/android application on a smartphone

Tags: android, testing, cordova, executable, smartphone

I have developped my first application with PhoneGap/Android, normally it will be functional on any smartphone, I have now a blackberry, and I want to know how to create an executable of my application and then test it on the smartphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PhoneGap build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) for this! Create an account, then upload the .zip file of your web application , then you can build executable files for many mobile SE.

Answer (score 1):

Check [get started](http://phonegap.com/start/#blackberry) guide of phonegap

Comment: I found:
 Deploy to Device:
*Make sure USB debugging is enabled on your device and plug it into your system. (Settings > Applications > Development)

*Right click the project and go to Run As and click Android Application

I haven't undertood:
plug it into your system. (Settings > Applications > Development)

Comment: Are you deploying for blackberry or android?

Comment: I have developped using phonegap with Android platform, and now I want to test it in a blackberry device

Comment: Ok.. did you deploy the application with Blackberry SDK as described on blackberry tab? Or detailed guide http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/31930982/Getting-Started-with-PhoneGap-BlackBerry-WebWorks

Comment: You must deploy for Blackberry to run your application on Blackberry devices. As i know, apk files can not be installed Blackberry devices.

Comment: no, I haven't, but should I deploy the application with every smartphone (blackberry or android or ..)? I thought that I should have an executable, then run it into any smartphone

Comment: no.. you got only html files with capability of access resources that comes with phonegap. you must deploy (not writing application for these devices, just deploy) for every platform that you want to use.